# Show that if any $k+1$ vertices of $k-$connected graph with at least 3 vertices span at least one-edge, then the graph is hamiltonian.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

Show that if $G$ is a $k$-connected graph with at least 3 vertices such that any $k+1$ vertices of $G$ span at least one edge, then the graph is hamiltonian.

I know that a graph is said to be $k$-connected if there does not exist a set of $k-1$ vertices whose removal disconnects the graph. Also, a graph is hamiltonian if it contains a hamiltonian cycle, which is a cycle that visits every vertex exactly once.

This problem has been getting to me for the past two days and I would really appreciate some assistance in solving this. It comes from the book *Modern Graph Theory* by Bela Bollobas.

Many thanks in advance for your time and suggestions.

Comment: First observe what is a Hamiltonian; A graph G on n ≥ 3 vertices

Comment: κ(G) A connected graph G is k-connected if |V (G)| ≥ k+1 and G−S is connected for any set S ⊂ V (G) of at most k−1 vertices. In other words, no two vertices are separated by a set of k − 1 vertices.

Comment: "with at least 3 vertices span at least one-edge" what does that mean?

Comment: This is the Chvatal-Erdos theorem: if $G$ is a graph on at least $3$ vertices such that $\alpha(G) \leq \kappa(G)$, then $G$ is Hamiltonian.